# How to plot a horizontal bar chart in python matplolib from the output table of previous line?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have executed the following line in python:

```
teams = train.groupby('localTeam')['local_won'].sum()
print (teams)
```

and got this as output :

```
localTeam
AD Almeria                    37
AD Ceuta                      11
Alaves                       263
Albacete                     210
Alcorcon                      79
Alcoyano                       6
Algeciras                     31
Alicante                       2
Almeria                      152
Alzira                         7
Aragon                         8
Athletic Club                502
Atletico Madrileno            93
Atletico Marbella             33
Atletico de Madrid           544
Aviles                        13
Badajoz                       78
Barakaldo                     70
Barcelona                    652
Barcelona Atletic            195
Betis                        467
Bilbao Athletic              111
Burgos                       126
Burgos CF                      4
CD Malaga                    201
Cadiz                        289
Calvo Sotelo                  50
Cartagena                     49
Castellon                    292
Castilla                     222
                            ... 
Pontevedra                    45
Racing de Ferrol              66
Racing de Santander          386
Rayo Vallecano               407
Real Burgos                   58
Real Madrid                  663
Real Oviedo                  332
Real Sociedad                483
Real Union                     8
Real Zaragoza                451
Recreativo de Huelva         310
Reus                           7
Sabadell                     231
Salamanca                    283
Sant Andreu                   86
Sestao                        80
Sevilla                      510
Sevilla Atletico              20
Sporting de Gijon            435
Tenerife                     375
Terrassa                      60
Toledo                        61
UCAM Murcia                    7
Universidad de Las Palmas      5
Valencia                     518
Valladolid                   449
Vecindario                     7
Villarreal                   273
Villarreal B                  26
Xerez                        168
Name: local_won, dtype: int64
```

Now I want to plot a horizontal barchart with the values sorted from highest to lowest.

Comment: dataset gets collapsed here. its actually a table with localTeam as column-1 header and no header for column-2

Comment: Please be clear in your question what it is you require in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may sort the Series by `.sort_values(ascending=False)` and you may plot it via `.plot(kind="bar")`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({"team":np.random.choice(list("ABCDE"), size=100), 
                   "won":np.random.randint(0,2, size=100)})

teams = df.groupby('team')['won'].sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
teams.plot(kind="bar")

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If this solves your issue, you may [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer, such that your question will not stay unsolved forever. Since you're new on SO, I might mention that you could take the [tour], read [ask] and [mcve] in order to improve your next questions you ask here.